# Qt shall we delete QNetworkReply* reply received on QNetworkAccessManager SIGNAL?

Tags: c++, qt

Say we have:

```
pManager  = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QObject::connect(pManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
```

and

```
 void finished(QNetworkReply* reply);
```

If we delete reply inside `finished` we will get segfault. Does this mean we shall not free it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html:

> Note: Do not delete the object in the slot connected to this signal. Use deleteLater().

Comment: So we can use deleteLater in the slot, right? That note is quite vague, but it makes sense to be deleted with deleteLater at the end of the slot.

Answer (score 4):

From the [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) docs for the `finished` signal:

> Note: **Do not delete the reply object in the slot connected to this signal. Use deleteLater().**

So indeed, you should not delete it, but call `deleteLater`.